# looping through a list of dictionaries to get a certain key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to loop through the list(locations) of dictionaries(Home, Work) and if oranges is < 1, then add that dictionary to the empty list (store).  How do I do this?  Here is my code set up below:

Home = {
    'oranges': 0,
    'apples': 2,
    'bananas': 1
}
Work = { 
    'oranges': 1,
    'apples': 0,
    'bananas': 4
}

locations = [Home, Work]

store = []

Comment: To be honest, I tried many different things that don't work.  I am new to python.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it using a list comprehension. It iterates over the dictionary list `locations` and tests the value of the `'orange'` key for each dictionary:

```
Home = { 'oranges': 0, 'apples': 2, 'bananas': 1 }
Work = { 'oranges': 1, 'apples': 0, 'bananas': 4 }
locations = [Home, Work]

store = [d for d in locations if 'oranges' in d and d.get('oranges') < 1]

>>> store
[{'apples': 2, 'oranges': 0, 'bananas': 1}]
```

This takes care not to include dictionaries that do not have `'orange'` as a key.

Note that you should use lower case variable names such as `home` and `work`.

Comment: Thanks.  How would I just add the name to that dictionary?  So that: store = [home]

Comment: For your input `store` does equal `[home]`.  Check `store[0] is home` -> True which means that they are the same dictionary. See this in action by updating `home` - the same change will happen to `store[0]` because it is the _same_ dictionary: `home['bananas'] += 1; print store[0]` and you'll see that `store[0]['bananas']` is now 2.